# Построение многоуровневого пространства с OpenGL + Qt

Tags: qt, opengl

Программирую на Qt, появилась задача сделать многоуровневую модель пространства с помощью OpenGL.

Если не вдаваться в подробности, есть основной кубик, на нем должны находиться другие кубики, в которых в свою очередь находятся кубики поменьше, т.е. вложенные объекты.

Проблема в том, что я на OpenGL никогда раньше не программировал и все примеры что я находил слишком поверхностные. Например, у Шлее М. есть раздел про OpenGL, но там просто объясняется как рисовать 3D треугольник, да и тот пример у меня по какой-то причине неправильно работает и отображается только в 2D. Поэтому прошу помочь с двумя проблемами:

1. Подсказать хороший, последовательный гайд по OpenGL, желательно на примерах в Qt.
2. Собственно, подсказать каким образом можно реализовать создание сложной модели, состоящей из кучи мелких элементов, некоторые из которых расположены внутри других.

Единичный кубик я нарисовать смог, но вот как нарисовать одновременно несколько таких кубиков я пока что не представляю.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам примерный алгоритм:

1. Научиться рисовать 3D треугольник
2. Научиться рисовать кубик из треугольников
3. Научиться рисовать два кубика с разными координатами/размерами
4. Построить структуру данных в которой будут описаны положения и размеру кубиков
5. Нарисовать что вам нужно по заданию.

Если вам нужно освещение, работа с камерой или еще какие-то вещи - учите туториалы и задавайте вопросы отдельно.